# Is there a free, small assembly code compiler/assembler for Windows?

Tags: assembly, compilation

What I want is something like g++ where I can type:

```
compiler_name my_assembly_code.extention
```

...and have it compile my assembly code. It does not matter whether it's 32 or 64 bit. Just needs to be for Windows.

Does anyone know of one that I can get that does this? I'm open to other suggestions as well, I just want to stay away from having to use MS Visual Studio for doing this.

Comment: Any reason besides MS hate you want to stay away from VS?

Comment: Yes, I don't like the plethora of files and crap that usually gets created when I use VS. For all my generic C++/C programming I use Notepad++ and MinGW and I love the simplicity of doing it this way. Generally, in the end I'm left with my C++/C files and an executable.

Comment: if you're already using MinGW, then you've got a working gas copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Almost) any normal distribution of g++ will/should include a copy of [`gas`](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/), the GNU Assembler. Depending on the distribution you get, the command you use may be `as` or `gas` (and some include both).

Unfortunately, at least the last time I tried it `gas` had quite a few bugs. It works fine for code that's generated by gcc/g++, but if you depart much from what it can/does produce, you can run into all sorts of problems. That, however, was some time ago, so these problems may have been fixed -- I don't know for sure.

There are quite a few alternatives as well. [NASM](http://www.nasm.us/) is probably the most widely used and gets updated (e.g., for new instruction sets) reasonably dependably.

Comment: I have MinGW, but no 'gas'. I do have 'as'. Is that the same thing?

Comment: @Mike Webb: yes, I believe so. I'd try something like `as --version` at the command line (with it on the path). Assuming it's the right thing, you should be a GNU Assembler banner with version number and such...

Comment: Yep, that's it. Thanks. Downloaded NASM too, just in case, but anytime I can use what I already have installed I am happy. So much development crap on my PC. lol

Answer (score 10):

There's lots.

- [nasm](http://www.nasm.us)
- [yasm](http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/)
- [flat assembler](http://flatassembler.net/).

All of which are capable of generating PE files. However, in order to do that, you need to understand the mode of operation required by said assembler. For example, it is entirely possible to use each assembler to generate obj files for linking, or you can write a pure binary output. If you do that, you'll need to create the appropriate executable header.

Flat assembler provides the `FORMAT PE` directive (see [here](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php?article=manual#2.4.2)) which greatly simplifies this process.

Comment: I really do like FASM. It is lean and mean and has an excellent macro preprocessor

Answer (score -1):

I personally use [TASM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tasmeditor/), I find it easier that MASM.